# Convert C# code to PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Given this piece of code:

```
someobject.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.ProgressPercentage);
```

How could I write the same thing in powershell, i used Register-Event but when i called the execute method on the object it just blocks the thread and you only see that the event has fired after the action is finished, I also tried to use Start-Job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Register-ObjectEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx) should work:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $someobject -EventName ProgressChanged `
    -Action { Write-Host $EventArgs.ProgressPercentage }
```

See [this TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/16/use-asynchronous-event-handling-in-powershell.aspx) for more information about asynchronous event handling in PowerShell.

**EDIT:** As requested in comments, here is the code I used in my tests:

```
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 500
$timer.AutoReset = $true
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed `
    -Action { Write-Host $EventArgs.SignalTime }
$timer.Start()
```

From there on, the signal times of the `Elapsed` events were printed to the console every half second until I managed to blind-type `$timer.Stop()`.

Comment: I probably wasn't  clear enough, you can use Register-ObjectEvent to subscribe to the event but it still only fires after the execution of my method has completed

Comment: @Taylor, interesting, I tested the code above with a timer and the handler was definitely called asynchronously. Where and how are you triggering the `ProgressChanged` event? Is it coming from a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: my suspicious were right, its actually the library that i am using that is causing this behavior with its MRE.